# Select PHP's Image resizing algorithm

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, bilinear-interpolation

The function [imagecopyresampled](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is useful to generate a thumbnail or resize images, while keeping aspect ratio:

```
$fn = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];
$size = getimagesize($fn);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
$ratio = $width / $height;
if ($ratio > 1 && $size[0] > 500) { $width = 500; $height = 500 / $ratio; }
else { if ($ratio <= 1 && $size[1] > 500) { $width = 500 * $ratio; $height = 500; }}
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fn));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
imagedestroy($src);
imagejpeg($dst, 'test.jpg');
imagedestroy($dst);
```

**How can I select the resizing algorithm used by PHP?**
*Note: as stated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41729409/1422096), setting `imagesetinterpolation($dst, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED);` or such things doesn't seem to work.*

---

According to tests I did (in another language), "bilinear resizing" sometimes gives better result than bicubic, and sometimes it's the contrary (depends if it's downsizing or upsizing).

[image]
<sub>(source: [dpchallenge.com](https://www.dpchallenge.com/tutorial/8/images/resize_largematrix1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: As noted [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresampled.php#54448) by someone: "It should be noted that the imagecopyresampled() function is much more blurry than Photoshop CS's default bicubic funtion. And looks similar to a blury version of Photoshop's bilinear function. The documentation fails to note which algorithm is used in resampling."

Comment: It looks like it doesn't apply to imagecopyresampled - I shall delete it as incorrect while I try to work it out. Sorry.

Comment: As stated [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41729409/1422096), setting `imagesetinterpolation($dst, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED);` or such things doesn't seem to work.

Comment: _"How can I modify the resizing algorithm used by PHP?"_ wouldn't it be easier to just write your own custom PHP function rather than modify the programming language itself (if that's even allowed)?

Comment: I've edited a keyword in your Question, since I understand it better now. Don't say _"I want to **modify** algorithm X"_ when really you mean _"I want to **select** option of algorithm X"_... The former suggests you want to modify PHP source code's functions. You just want to enable some resize option... correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative is the [`imagescale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php) function, that allows specifying the interpolation algorithm as a parameter:

```
imagescale($image, $new_width, $new_height, $algorithm);
```

According to the documentation `$algorithm` can be:

> One of `IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR`, `IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED`, `IMG_BICUBIC`, `IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED` or anything else (will use two pass).

A test in PHP 7.0.15 (comparing file hash) shows that BICUBIC and BICUBIC_FIXED result in a different image, while BILINEAR_FIXED and NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR result in the same image.

Comment: Seems great! I'll test asap.

Comment: @Basj this is the Answer I was going to give myself. I think it's correct for your needs...?

Comment: For me using `imagescale()` with `IMG_BICUBIC` makes the image even blurrier, and introduces weird artifact in flat colours.

Comment: I can't say which filter produces the best results but avoid using `IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED`, `IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED` and `IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR` as those methods produce really bad images (I tested downscaling).

Comment: An important note is the "or anything else" in the manual. I noticed that I can use many more filter types, listed here https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagesetinterpolation.php . Probably all except IMG_WEIGHTED4 (see php manual for imagescale). I had good results with e.g. IMG_CATMULLROM for downscaling (tested in PHP 7).

Answer (score 5):

`imagecopyresampled` is based/part of LibGD , by looking at the source code of LibGD, you can see clearly its [implementation](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/7e3587af06c7f89cb749442a689638241b486afb/src/gd.c#L3452) , also the documentation is not ambiguous about the used algorithm as it's stated that :

> If the source and destination area differ in size, the area will be resized using **bilinear interpolation** for truecolor images, and **nearest-neighbor interpolation** for palette images.

So how can you select the resizing algorithm used by PHP?

If you **insist/must** use LibGD functions, you can't (unless you recompile PHP with a LibGD fork you code just for this matter).

However if you're free to use another image manipulation library, you can simply use one that use a different algorithm for resizing, for example Imagick seems to offer a wide range of interpolations but since the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageinterpolatemethod.php) is quite mute about it here is the constants needed to use the `Imagick::setImageInterpolateMethod(int $)` method :

```
const INTERPOLATE_UNDEFINED = 0;
const INTERPOLATE_AVERAGE = 1;
const INTERPOLATE_BICUBIC = 2;
const INTERPOLATE_BILINEAR = 3;
const INTERPOLATE_FILTER = 4;
const INTERPOLATE_INTEGER = 5;
const INTERPOLATE_MESH = 6;
const INTERPOLATE_NEARESTNEIGHBOR = 7;
const INTERPOLATE_SPLINE = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use a library? I think that if you use a php library it will be more easy. Try [this one](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize). Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Cakpep check the new edit & re-read for true meaning of Question. You can [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41889086/edit) your Answer with new info, if you wish...

Comment: This library won't allow to change algorithm. See [this comment](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize/issues/68): `http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php this is the function used internally by library. I could not find information on which algorithm is used by the function.`

Answer (score 0):

Well you could download the PHP Source , add your filter function and compile php.

here you can find the filters https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/libgd/gd_interpolation.c#L481

here is the switch case where you have to apply the method https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/libgd/gd_interpolation.c#L2530

here you can define constants https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/libgd/gd.h#L137

happy hacking :D

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this Answer. It's correct for the previous wording of Question which suggested the Asker wanted to modify the source code of a re-sampling algorithm. I've edited the Question. @VitalijMik, check the new edit if you wish to [**`change`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41889429/edit) your Answer also...